# Should I update the semver version when adding examples to a package?

Tags: github, npm, package, versioning, semantic-versioning

I'm making an npm package and I published it as version 1.0.0 because I was happy with the public API. But now, I'm in the process of adding an "examples" subproject to showcase how to use the library. Obviously, I won't publish the example project as a part of the library (it will be added in .npmignore), but it will be on my github repo. Is there any semantic versioning rules for that? Should I update the patch version, minor version or nothing at all?

On one hand, I think I shouldn't update the version since it won't be published to npm, therefore normal users of the app won't even notice a difference in the package. On the other hand, semver rules say you should update the "patch" or "minor" version when you make documentation changes, even though the documentation isn't published either.

Answer (score 0):

The [relevant spec here is #3](https://semver.org/#spec-item-3):

> 3. Once a versioned package has been released, the contents of that version MUST NOT be modified. Any modifications MUST be released as a new version.

Since nothing was added to your API and it's obviously not a breaking change, you should bump the patch number.

Comment: OP says _"I won't publish the example project as a part of the library"_ so it (i.e. examples) don't actually reach end user(s), nor does it even touch the npm repo/registry. Is this then still applicable/relevant under those circumstances? It seems more appropriate to bump an internal version number in these circumstances, than it is to bump the external user facing semver.

Comment: Yeah, that's the core of my dilemma. Spec says that when you update the docs (e.g. deprecation warning), you should bump the patch version, even though documentation isn't published anywhere and the checksum of the package would be exactly the same. But documentation is more linked to the functionnality than examples.

Comment: @AlesBorgue - The reality is; answers you get to your question will be _piimarily opinion-based_ as the semver documentation does not explicitly state what to do in your scenario. IMO semver should  _only_ be changed when you actually _release_ a new revision of the product to the public. Ultimately it acts as the core contract between you and your end customer/user to indicate how your software will behave/function if updated. Given your scenario you're not actually releasing anything. I'd leave as-is, but if you'd prefer to bump the _PATCH_ version then do it. - flip a coin if necessary ;)

Comment: Alright, thank you for your input! I discussed with my colleagues and we came to the conclusion that we will basically never update the semver when the checksum doesn't change, as the users would get no benefit updating to our version. This might also give them false hopes of bug fixes when literally nothing changed.

Comment: If the package being versioned does not change, and that includes its contents, the version number doesn't need to be changed. If you flip one bit of the content in the package, the spec is very clear that you must bump the version number. Given two packages with identical version numbers, the contents should be exactly the same.